# Conditional application of one of two functions to one argument

Tags: scala

I have two functions that take one argument, a `String`. I was to apply either one or the other based on some `condition`. This is what I attempted:

```
def foo(s: String) = { ... }
def bar(s: String) = { ... }
(if (condition) foo else bar)("baz")
```

But I get an error like this:

```
<console>:10: error: missing arguments for method foo;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
              (if (true) foo else bar)("baz")
                         ^
```

I tried writing `foo_` but of course I got `error: not found: value foo_`. What's the correct way to express this idiom in Scala?

Comment: `foo_` is not following `foo` with `_` it's attempting to call method `foo_`.  This may seem weird to someone coming from other languages as it may be that using `_` in method names is not allowed.

Comment: @samthebest Yeah, I know `_` is allowed in the method name so I thought it was strange. I guess seeing that I was supposed to write `foo _` makes me realize that I just misinterpreted what the error was telling me to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a space between the method name and the underscore. This works fine:

```
def foo(s: String) = s + "-FOO"
def bar(s: String) = s + "-BAR"
val condition = true
(if (condition) foo _ else bar _)("baz")
// res0: String = baz-FOO
```

The underscore after the method name tells Scala that you want to want to pass the method as a higher-level function. From what I understand, this is a way to disambiguate whether you want to pass a method as a function or pass the result of a method with no arguments. For example:

```
def f = 1
val x = Some(f)
```

What should the type of `x` be? Will it be `Some[Int]` or `Some[()=>Int]`? It should default to the former, but if you want the latter you can use the underscore notation:

```
val y = Some(f _)
```

---

You have to deal with all this underscore nonsense because [*Scala methods aren't functions*](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/05/scala-functions-vs-methods.html). If you declare `foo` and `bar` as functions rather than methods then your original code works as-is:

```
val foo = (s: String) => s + "-FOO"
val bar = (s: String) => s + "-BAR"
val condition = false
(if (condition) foo else bar)("baz")
// res1: String = baz-BAR
```

Comment: def f = 1 is a method not function :)

Comment: Oh, right, I misinterpreted the error message. I remember in a book I'm reading on Scala that the `_` is a sort of "placeholder" so this makes sense to me now, sort of. Except for the fact that `def` outside of the body of a class is still declaring a method not a function, that's throwing me off.

Comment: @2rs2ts - What do you mean by "outside the body of a class"? Do you mean you're doing a `def` in the Scala interpreter (REPL)? If so, you should know that everything you type in the REPL is implicitly wrapped in an object definition. You can actually type `this` in the REPL to get a reference to that enclosing object.

Comment: In the REPL or in a file with no `class`/`object` declaration, yeah. So if in the former it gets wrapped in an implicit `object` definition, I assume the same goes for files with no `class`/`object` declaration?

Comment: @2rs2ts - I've actually never written a Scala "script" like that (I kind of forgot that functionality existed). But yes, I think that's a safe assumption to make since the JVM doesn't allow anything to exist outside a class definition. To confirm, try putting `println(this)` in your file and see what happens.

Comment: @2rs2ts In fact, your script is wrapped in a local class; usually that's unsurprising, but you run into bugs you wouldn't see otherwise like https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7121

Answer (score 1):

There are several things I want to mention:

def foo(s: String) = { ... }
def bar(s: String) = { ... }

foo and bar are not functions, there are just normal method. Also, def f = 3 is also a **method** not **function**.

(if (condition) foo else bar)("baz") obviously, this statement need foo and bar to be a **function** because of ("baz") argument.

as @wendao mentioned to use _ to change method to function. I think the simplest solution is to define foo and bar as a function.

```
def foo: String => String = { value => 
  "Hi " + value
}

def bar: String => String = { value =>
  "farewell " + value
}

val x: Some[String => String] = Some(foo)

(if (true) foo else bar)("John")    // Hi John
```

Comment: Not exactly intuitive to me (I'm coming from Python) but I'll bite. If it's a method, to which class does it belong?

Comment: If it is a method, it doesn't belong to any type, it just has a return type. However, a function will belong to a trait Function0, Function1, Function2, Function3 and so forth. For this case, def f(x: String): String = "123"

(f _).isInstanceOf[Function0[_]] //false
(f _).isInstanceOf[Function1[_, _]] //true. In scala, function is object, I always consider method is special form of function. For example, if you have argument which accept a function, it actually can use method instead. def add3(x: Int) = x + 3 List(1,2,3).map(add3). map accept a function not method.

Comment: So in Scala, there can exist methods which do not belong to a class at all?

Comment: No, you cant, I think I misunderstand you before. Method has to belong to a trait, class, object.

Comment: I think the question should be what is method type or function type, not method or function belong to. :)

Comment: I think you should read this http://java.dzone.com/articles/revealing-scala-magician%E2%80%99s

Comment: `((if (true) f else g): (String => String))("hi")` works for method f,g. Also, `val f = (s: String) => s"hi, $s"` or `val f: String => String = "hi " + _`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't know that what you actually want to return a function, you'd have to tell it that what you want is a by-name parameter:

```
  def foo(x : String) = x                         //> foo: (x: String)String
  def bar(x : String) = x                         //> bar: (x: String)String
  val condition = true                            //> condition  : Boolean = true

  val result : String => String = if (condition) foo else bar
                                                  //> result  : String => String = <function1>
  result("something")                             //> res0: String = something
```

Comment: So `result` is a `val` containing a function?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more absurd:

```
scala> var b = true
b: Boolean = true

scala> def f(s: String) = s"f+$s"
f: (s: String)String

scala> def g(s: String) = s"g+$s"
g: (s: String)String

scala> import Function._ ; import PartialFunction._
import Function._
import PartialFunction._

scala> unlift(condOpt(_: String) { case s if b => f(s) }) applyOrElse ("hi", g)
res0: String = f+hi

scala> b = false
b: Boolean = false

scala> unlift(condOpt(_: String) { case s if b => f(s) }) applyOrElse ("hi", g)
res1: String = g+hi
```